# Amazon Selling Partner Api - empty profiles

Tags: amazon-advertising-api

Currently I am developing an app that uses Amazon's Advertising API. So far already done the required process. I can test the api using the sandbox. However, for getting real data, I cant get profileId as value for the `Amazon-Advertising-API-Scope` parameters required by Amazon. Works fine with sand box because sandbox has api to create dummy profile. At first I thought the LWA( the Login with amazon button) will return the profile information but I was wrong. It only return profile:CustomerId, and primary email. I tried to use the customerId but it doesnt work.

My question is, what are the necessary steps to when I call the /profiles endpoint it will return the profiles ? My LWA works fine. But when I call the /profiles end point it return empty list.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

**Read Here** https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/info/api-overview#api-endpoints

While using the API endpoint **"{{baseUrl}}/v2/profiles"**, make sure you pass the correct baseURL based on your region.

For example for Sandbox Environment I used "**https://advertising-api-test.amazon.com**/v2/profiles" as it covers all marketplace .

For India region I used "**https://advertising-api-eu.amazon.com**/v2/profiles"

**Your endpoint is returning empty list because**  the user account does not have any advertising account in the region(baseURL)that you must have passed in your API call
[image: Reason for getting empty profile]